# c# password causes a dangerous request on submit

Tags: c#, passwords

First of all, I know this question has been asked a million times before and I have ready a huge amount of responses to this question, however I wanted to know if there is an alternative to the standard response.

My problem, on my signup page, I request a user to provide an account password.

The user input is encoded using Server.HttpEncode and then encrypted and hashed and finally passed to a Stored Procedure for addition into the database.

This does work ok, however on the odd occasion when a user enters a password of characters, I will receive a Dangerous Request.

My question is: is there any way of stopping this dangerous request without setting validateRequest="false"?

I would prefer to not add validation to the password (e.g. only alphanumberic values)

Please, suggestions are welcome....

Regards

Comment: why don't you want to set `validateRequest` to `"false"`?

Comment: @AbeMiessler I think he wants to stop the dangerous request `exception`

Comment: Sam I am, if I set validateRequest to false how can I guarantee 100% that the input cannot be compromised? Im sure there are encoded characters that can get around Server.HttpEncode

Comment: So you saying that you want to guarantee 100% of the input cannot be dangerous, but you want to accept dangerous input(only for passwords) **at the same time**

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for this. You can handle it in the Global class or in your page class.
More details: [Handle "potentially dangerous Request.Form value..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890559/handle-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value)